# Pandas - Find rolling average of past 3 days

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to find the average of the past 3 days of data for a specific group of elements as shown below. Given below is how my Dataframe looks like:

```
day, category, sub-category, count
2021-01-01, electronic, phone, 10
2021-01-02, electronic, phone, 12
2021-01-03, electronic, phone, 3
2021-01-04, electronic, phone, 20
2021-01-01, electronic, computer, 15
2021-01-02, electronic, computer, 12
2021-01-03, electronic, computer, 20
```

Expected output

```
day, category, sub-category, count, rolling_average_past_3_days
2021-01-01, electronic, phone, 10,
2021-01-02, electronic, phone, 12,
2021-01-03, electronic, phone, 3, 8.3
2021-01-04, electronic, phone, 20, 11.6
2021-01-01, electronic, computer, 15,
2021-01-02, electronic, computer, 12,
2021-01-03, electronic, computer, 20, 15.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['rolling_average_past_3_days'] = df.groupby('sub-category')['count'].rolling(3).mean().droplevel(0)
```

or

```
df.groupby('sub-category',sort=False).rolling('3D',on='day')['count'].mean().to_numpy()
```

Comment: thanks for getting back.. I tried the above bu it returns a new column with all NANs

Comment: interesting, it worked for me... when you run just `df.groupby('sub-category')['count'].rolling(3).mean()` does it return what you are expecting (outside your df)

Comment: thats interesting... the only other thing I can think of is to check that your `count` column is a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

To be generic that you can have more than one main category beside 'electronic', you need to group by category too.  You need also to use [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) so that the result get broadcasted back to the original structure so that you can get all entries.  Otherwise, you may get error like: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

You can try this:

```
df['rolling_average_past_3_days'] = df.groupby(['category', 'sub-category'])['count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean())

print(df)

          day    category sub-category  count  rolling_average_past_3_days
0  2021-01-01  electronic        phone     10                          NaN
1  2021-01-02  electronic        phone     12                          NaN
2  2021-01-03  electronic        phone      3                     8.333333
3  2021-01-04  electronic        phone     20                    11.666667
4  2021-01-01  electronic     computer     15                          NaN
5  2021-01-02  electronic     computer     12                          NaN
6  2021-01-03  electronic     computer     20                    15.666667
```

The `NaN` values shown on the first 2 entries of each sub-category is normal since you are rolling averaving over the 3 days and the first 2 days have no value.  If you want to make them blank instead of showing `NaN`, you can use this:

```
df['rolling_average_past_3_days'] = df.groupby(['category', 'sub-category'])['count'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean()).replace(np.nan, '')


print(df)

          day    category sub-category  count rolling_average_past_3_days
0  2021-01-01  electronic        phone     10                            
1  2021-01-02  electronic        phone     12                            
2  2021-01-03  electronic        phone      3                    8.333333
3  2021-01-04  electronic        phone     20                   11.666667
4  2021-01-01  electronic     computer     15                            
5  2021-01-02  electronic     computer     12                            
6  2021-01-03  electronic     computer     20                   15.666667
```